# How can I connect the dots in a plot using Pine Script on TradingView?

Tags: tradingview-api

I want to draw a plot (curve line) among the given dots

here's my code:

I want to connect all of this lines or make somehow the line be consistent

Looking forward for your help, guys :)

```
/@version=4
study("My Script")

pma2 = array.from(28010.0, 26130.0, 26230.0, 25050.0, 25300.0)

plot(array.get(pma2, 0), title="MA Forecast", color=color.rgb(242, 218, 6), linewidth=1, offset=1, show_last=1, style=plot.style_cross)
plot(array.get(pma2, 1), color=color.yellow, linewidth=1, offset=2, show_last=1, style=plot.style_cross)
plot(array.get(pma2, 2), color=color.yellow, linewidth=1, offset=3, show_last=1, style=plot.style_cross)
plot(array.get(pma2, 3), color=color.yellow, linewidth=1, offset=4, show_last=1, style=plot.style_cross)
plot(array.get(pma2, 4), color=color.yellow, linewidth=1, offset=5, show_last=1, style=plot.style_cross)
```

here's what I get  (attached screenshot)